# Get the href value using HTML5 data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to get the value of the href i.e. the web link using the data attribute.

I have the following snippet of code

```
<div class="my-item-details">

    <h3 class="my-item-title" data-item_item="x12"> 
        <a href="http://link.com">
            My Classic Box
        </a>
    </h3>

    <span class="my-item-price" data-item_item="x12">   
        38.00
    </span>

</div>
```

The following 2 snippets give the right output.

```
var price_val = $('.my-item-price[data-item_uuid=x12]').text();
price_val = $.trim(price_val)
console.log(price_val);
```

**38.00**

```
var item_name = $('.my-item-title[data-item_uuid=x12]').text();
item_name = $.trim(item_name)
console.log(item_name);
```

**My Classic Box**

However when I run this code

```
var item_link = $('.my-item-title[data-item_uuid=x12]').attr("href");
item_link = $.trim(item_link)
console.log(item_link);
```

I get an **empty string** instead of http://link.com

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.my-item-title[data-item_uuid=x12]` selects the `h3` element, which doesn't have an `href` attribute.

Only the `a` element has that.

Add a descendant combinator and a type selector:

```
.my-item-title[data-item_uuid=x12] a
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to get the attribute href from a `<h3>` element without href property:

You could make a change on your selector this way to get the correct result:

```
var item_link = $('.my-item-title[data-item_uuid=x12] > a').attr("href");
```

This should give you the correct value.